# Trying to hide inputField - Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, class

Im trying to hide my Billing_Account__c inputField on my visualforce page, If my custom field Entitas_New__c = 'Pusat' on my custom object Master_Visit_Plan__c.

This is the vf page, as you can see there`s billing account inputfield :
[image]

My custom object relationship :
Master_Visit_Plan__c (Parent) -> Master_Visit_Plan_Branch__c -> Visit_Plan_Header__c -> Visit_Plan__c

The vf page appear if user press New Visit Plan button on Visit_Plan_Header__c page. (user doesnt have to go to visit_plan tab to create new record, but from master visit plan -> create master visit plan -> visit plan header -> create visit plan)

[image]

I tried using rendered with IF condition to hide the billing account inputfield. It works. The inputField disappeared. But its totally disappeared, even if Entitas_New__c != 'Pusat'.

[image]

this is my vf :

```
<apex:page controller="Visit_plan_class">
<apex:form id="formid">
    <apex:message />
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageMessages id="errors"/>
        <apex:pageblockbuttons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!add}" rerender="formid"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="delete" action="{!deletede}"/>
        </apex:pageblockbuttons>

       <apex:pageblocktable value="{!listvp}" var="var">
           <apex:column headerValue="Cancel">
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!var.cek}"/>
            </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Visit Plan Header"> 
                 <apex:outputfield value="{!var.vp2.Visit_Plan_Header__c}"/>
           </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Koordinator Visit"> 
                 <apex:inputfield value="{!var.vp2.Named_User__c}"/>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Description"> 
                <apex:inputfield value="{!var.vp2.Description__c}"/>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Customer"> 
                <apex:inputfield value="{!var.vp2.Customer_VF__c}"/>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Billing Account">
               <apex:inputfield value="{!var.vp2.Billing_Account__c}" rendered="{IF(!var.vp2.Visit_Plan_Header__r.Master_Visit_Plan_Branch__r.Master_Visit_Plan__r.Entitas_New__c='Pusat',false,true)}"/>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Lead"> 
                <apex:inputfield value="{!var.vp2.Lead__c}"/>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Plan Date"  > 
               <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(var.vp2.id=='',true,false)}">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!var.vp2.Plan_Date__c}"/>
               </apex:outputPanel>
               <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(var.vp2.id=='',false,true)}">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!var.vp2.Plan_Date__c}"/>
               </apex:outputPanel>     
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Reschedule Date" > 
                <apex:inputfield value="{!var.vp2.Reschedule_Date__c}" rendered="{!if(var.vp2.id=='',false,true)}"/>
           </apex:column>



       </apex:pageblocktable>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

and this is the controller :

```
public class Visit_plan_class {
public List <Visit_Plan__c> vplist {get;set;}
public List <classVP> listvp {get;set;}

public String idsf{get;set;}
public String kondisi{get;set;}
public String PeriodeTxt{get;set;}
public String HeaderTxt{get;set;}
public String KoorPiC{get;set;}

private ApexPages.StandardController std;

public Visit_plan_class(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    std = controller;
    visit_plan_class2();
}

public Visit_plan_class(){
    visit_plan_class2();
}

public void visit_plan_class2(){
    listvp = new List<classVP>();
    vplist = new List<visit_plan__c>();
    kondisi = 'new';
    idsf = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    if(idsf!=null)
    {
        kondisi = 'update';
        vplist = [SELECT id,Lead__c,named_user__c, description__c,customer__c,Customer_VF__c ,billing_account__c, plan_date__c,reschedule_date__c,visit_plan_header__c,Master_Visit_Plan__r.Periode__c,
                  Master_Visit_Plan__r.Entitas_New__c, Visit_Plan_Header__r.Name
                FROM visit_plan__c WHERE Visit_Plan_Header__c =:idsf];

        Visit_Plan_Header__c vph = [SELECT id, Master_Visit_Plan_Branch__r.Master_Visit_Plan__r.Periode__c, Name, Master_Visit_Plan_Branch__r.Koor_PIC_Customer_Visit__c,
                                    Master_Visit_Plan__r.Entitas_New__c FROM Visit_Plan_Header__c WHERE id =: idsf];

        PeriodeTxt = vph.Master_Visit_Plan_Branch__r.Master_Visit_Plan__r.Periode__c;
        HeaderTxt = vph.Name;
        KoorPiC = vph.Master_Visit_Plan_Branch__r.Koor_PIC_Customer_Visit__c;

        if(vplist.size()>0){
            for(visit_plan__c oks:vplist){
                listvp.add(new classvp(false,oks));
            }              
        }
    }
}

public class classVP{
    public Boolean cek{get;set;}
    public visit_plan__c vp2 {get;set;}
    public classVP(Boolean a, Visit_Plan__c b){
        this.cek = a;
        this.vp2 = b;
    }
}


public void add(){
    Visit_plan__c vp2 = new visit_plan__c();

    vp2.Named_User__c = id.valueof(KoorPiC);

    Integer Year = Integer.ValueOf(PeriodeTxt);

    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('Januari')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 1, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('Februari')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 2, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('Maret')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 3, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('April')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 4, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('Mei')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 5, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('Juni')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 6, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('Juli')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 7, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('Agustus')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 8, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('September')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 9, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('Oktober')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 10, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('November')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 11, 1);        
    }
    if (HeaderTxt.Contains('Desember')){
        vp2.Plan_Date__c = Date.newInstance(Year, 12, 1);        
    } 
    //listvps.add(vp2);  
    //System.debug('Test:' + vp2.id);
    listvp.add(new classvp(false,vp2));

}

public pageReference save(){
    try{
        List<visit_plan__c> listvps = new List<visit_plan__c>();
        for(classvp cvp:listvp){
            if(cvp.cek==false){
                cvp.vp2.visit_plan_header__c = idsf;
                listvps.add(cvp.vp2);    
            }

        }
        upsert listvps;
    }catch(Exception e){
       if (PesanError.Contains('DUPLICATE_VALUE'))
           ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Customer / Billing Account sudah pernah dibuat.'));
       else if (!PesanError.Contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'))
           ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, ''+e.getMessage()));

       return null;
    }

    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+idsf);
    return pr;


}

Public void deletede()
{
    List <Visit_Plan__c> vp3 = new List<Visit_Plan__c>();
    List <classVP> classvp2 = new List <classVP>();
    for(classVP cvp2:listvp)
    {
        if(cvp2.cek==true){
            if(cvp2.vp2.id!=null) vp3.add(cvp2.vp2);
        }else{
            classvp2.add(cvp2);
        }
    }
    listvp = classvp2;
    try{
        if(vp3.size()>0) delete vp3;
    }catch(exception e){}

}

public PageReference cancel(){
    schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = visit_actual__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
    String keyPrefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
    String idini = '';
    if(idsf!=null) idini = idsf;
    else idini = keyprefix;
    PageReference  pr = new PageReference('/'+idini);
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;

}
```

}

can someone help me or give me reference

Comment: try to use outputpannel.check that condition using rendered

Answer (score 0):

You may just have to debug a bit more here. Just remove the rendered condition for now and print your Entitas_New__c value before tag `apex:inputfield` and see the output just like as I shown below- Once you seen the output you will get to know whether you are receiving correct value from apex controller or not-

{!var.vp2.Visit_Plan_Header__r.Master_Visit_Plan_Branch__r.Master_Visit_Plan__r.Entitas_New__c} : apex:inputfield value="{!var.vp2.Billing_Account__c}"